# Is there shortcut or macro for encapsulating highlighted text in quotes?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have a string without quotes, but I would like quotes to be on both ends without needing to click in front and then in back and add a quote - is such a thing possible through the Ribbon or VBA?

Bonus question: If I have a range of cells selected, is it possible to copy the reference rather than the values?  A Copy Special that would let me copy A2:B5, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a macro supporting our daily routine activities is not a bad thing:) 
Here's the macro that does the job:

```
Sub QuoteCell()
    ActiveCell.Value = """" & ActiveCell.Value & """"
End Sub
```

Later you can add a shortcut in Ribbon-->Developer-->Macros
[image]

From now on whenever you use your defined shortcut the value in cell gets surrounded with quotes.